# Remove / prevent loading of font-awesome in SAP Spartacus storefront

Tags: spartacus-storefront

In my current project i am working on a SAP Commerce Cloud Storefront based on SAP Spartacus.

I was trying to find a way to remove the loading of the default font-awesome icon font from SAP Spartacus as we use our own icon font in the project.

The font url is provided within projects/storefrontlib/cms-components/misc/icon/fontawesome-icon.config.ts which is part of the icon.module, which is used in various components.

I cant find a way to change this config as i am only able to override the icon symbol via provideConfig method.

I am looking for a recipe to remove font-awesome via config or something else to prevent the usage of font-awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right. You can use `provideConfig(<IconConfig>{ ... })` globally to override default icon configurations which would include the loading of font-awesome resources in favour of your custom symbols and resources.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, i added a empty url value in the IconConfig and font-awesome is not loaded anymore:

```
provideConfig({
      icon: {
        symbols: {
        ....
        },
        resources: [
          {
            type: IconResourceType.LINK,
            url: '',
          },
        ],
      },
    } as IconConfig),
```